# Why is name attribute transformed to value on input type in Web Essentials Zen Coding? Bug?

Tags: visual-studio-2012, web-essentials, emmet

In Visual Studio 2012 with **Web Essentials 3.5** the following Zen Coding item seems to be transformed improperly:

```
input[name="demo"][type="text"]
```

**Note:** *Just updated to version **web essentials 3.6.5** and I still get the incorrect markup.*

It results in :

[image: name attribute converted to value attribute]

I expected it to create the name attribute set to a value of demo like the following:

[image: expected result]

Does anyone know if this is a bug in Web Essentials 3.5 running under Visual Studio 2012?

Is there a list of bugs somewhere?

Did I type the Zen Code incorrectly?  Should I expect a different result?

Comment: FYI - Just installed web essentials 3.7 and this is still a bug.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay, because of all the samples people provided me with I began trying even more combinations and finally learned that **if I uppercase the NAME attribute, then it works**.
What?

Here's the zen code which actually works:

```
input[type="text" NAME="demo"]
```

or

```
input[type="text"][NAME="demo"]
```

Finally, I even tried UPPERCASING one letter in name like (notice uppercase 'A'):

```
input[type="text"][nAme="demo"]
```

All these result in:

[image: markup result]

Crazy.  Mark this down as a bug.  :)

Comment: That's good to know.  Could be frustrating for future internet goers.

Answer (score 0):

Your markup should work... it could be a bug with the Visual Studio plugin.  Does it support 
`input:t[name="demo"]` ?

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  Your sample results in the same incorrect markup I displayed above.  Thanks for additional try though. Also, I just learned there is a new version of Web Essentials (3.6.5) and updated/installed that one but it still fails.